# HTML stops at a PHP script made to connect to a mysql database. No errors printed

Tags: php, login-script

I'm trying to set up a login script for PHP using the tutorial on [this](http://www.evolt.org/node/60265) site. The problem is that the site stops when it hits these lines, no error, no text:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('error line7' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('mydb', $conn) or die('error line8' . mysql_error());
?>
```

If I take out these lines, the rest of the html runs perfectly. I've double checked my passwords and everything, nothing is working.
I know very little about php and mysql other than what I've learned trying to set this up.

Comment: off topic - you might want to stop using the mysql functions, which are old and not maintained (except security issues). Instead use PDO or MYSQLI (mysql improved)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. The internet evolves so quickly it's hard to find out what's current sometimes. Typing "php login script" into google just gives me a bunch of tutorials from about '05. Not the safest, I wager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have errors enabled.

Try enabling them before those lines like so

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Good luck.

Comment: That answers a lot. It was a problem with my server. Lacking a module.

Answer (score 1):

Beside all the other tips, which are good ones, Learn to `tail -f` the apache error log and the mysql log (all the possible logs which make sense to follow).
While in development. that is.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("YOUR QUERY")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        // do what you want with resutls
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the MySQL extensions are enabled in your install PHP. You can check by putting the following in one file and falling from the browser:

```
 <?
     phpinfo();
 ?>
```

It's a lengthy page, but it tells you almost everything about your PHP install. Including what extensions are installed.